# How do I arrange raw data in Google spreadsheet in group way?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have a list of orders, like this:

```
Paid    $28.00 | 2019-04-08 15:14:20
Unpaid  $00.00 | 2019-04-08 15:13:48
Unpaid  $00.00 | 2019-04-08 15:12:58
Unpaid  $00.00 | 2019-04-08 15:12:10
Paid    $18.00 | 2019-04-08 14:14:20
Paid    $18.00 | 2019-04-08 13:13:48
Paid    $58.00 | 2019-04-08 13:12:58
Unpaid  $00.00 | 2019-04-08 12:12:10
```

I want to turn them into numbers by hour, like this:

```
Date/Time     | Total | Paid | Total 
2019-04-08 12 | 0     | 1   | 1
2019-04-08 13 | 76    | 2   | 2
2019-04-08 14 | 18    | 1   | 1 
2019-04-08 15 | 28    | 1   | 4
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Date/Time", "Total", "Paid", "Total"; 
 {QUERY({LEFT(B1:B, 13), IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A, " "))}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3),count(Col1) 
  where Col2 matches 'Paid' 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col3)'',count(Col1)''", 0),
 VLOOKUP(QUERY(QUERY({LEFT(B1:B, 13), IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A, " "))}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3),count(Col1) 
  where Col2 matches 'Paid' 
  group by Col1", 0),
 "select Col1"),
 QUERY({LEFT(B1:B, 13), IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A, " "))},
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1", 0), 2, 0)}})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That's what I want. Thanks!